# How to check if a node belongs to another node in a tree

Tags: java, node.js, database, tree

I have a tree of users and I need to check if an user is below another specific user.
In example: check if user7 is below user1 somewhere in the tree so user1 can see and manage the data of user7 (see the image I've attached).In this case it should be true What will be the best/ a good approach to do this?

[image]

Edit: I don't think just traveling the tree until it find the ancestor will work because if the users are in a database it will need multiple relational queries and won't be scalable

Edit: What I trying to achieve is an app where an user can manage the users that the user registers and those that the latter registers as well, and so on. Like in the image, user admin can manage all, user 1 can manage user 3,4 and 5 and all below them too. User4 can manage user6. User 1 can't manage user 2 neither user3 to user7

Edit: one approach I have figured is to create in a SQL database a user_administrators property in the users database table that have an array of user_id who can manage it and when they register an user just inherit all the users_id and add itself to it. But I don't know if there's a better way to do it or a more scalable way

Comment: Is this node.js or java? How is the tree represented? What is your input - a reference to the node or just a user name? Please show relevant code.

Comment: It can be java or node.js that doesn't matter for me, What I need is the architecture solution. If i can do the solution in database or code or whatever then thats work for me haha. I don't have code because its the design of the architecture. Im not coding it yet. However, I will edit the question to provide more information.

Comment: Walk the tree until you find the ancestor (`user1`), then walk the subtree under that node to see if the descendent (`user7`) is present.

Comment: *"because if the users are in a database..."*: are they? If you don't know, how can we know? If they are to be in a database, which database engine are you using? Can you focus your question to a technology? A solution may look quite different in MongoDB, MySQL, or MS Access...

Comment: As I said, I'm searching for the best solution for the problem so I didn't want to put any technology stack in my question so I can use whatever is best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention a dependency on a database, here is an example of what you could do on an SQL database that supports recursive queries, such as MySQL 8+:

Creation of the schema:

```sql
create table user (
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    name varchar(100),
    manager_id int null
);
create index idx_user_name on user(name);
```

Populate with the example data given in the question:

```sql
insert into user(name) values("User Admin");
insert into user(name, manager_id)
    select name, (select id from user where name = "User Admin")
    from   (select "User 1" name union select "User 2") names;
insert into user(name, manager_id)
    select name, (select id from user where name = "User 1")
    from   (select "User 3" name union select "User 4" union select "User 5") names;
insert into user(name, manager_id)
    select "User 6", (select id from user where name = "User 2");
insert into user(name, manager_id)
    select "User 7", (select id from user where name = "User 4");
```

Now to know whether User 1 is in the manager line of User 7, perform this query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, name, manager_id
    from user where name = "User 7"
    union all
    select user.id, user.name, user.manager_id 
    from cte inner join user on cte.manager_id = user.id
)
select 1 from cte where name = "User 1";
```

This query first locates the record for "User 7" and then walks up the tree collecting all persons on the manager line. Finally a simple select checks whether "User 1" occurs in this line.

If this query has a result record (the 1 is irrelevant), then the answer is "Yes". If the query returns no record, the answer is no.

If you can use the `id` fields instead of the `name` fields to identify users, that would be preferable as names could be non-unique.

Comment: Wow this is actually a very good one! I'm gonna check on the performance of recursive cte to see how scalable it is but until now this is the best solution I have seen! Thank u

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that for every node you can either navigate top-down or bottom up.

If top down, have a function that assembles the list of subnodes recursively,
Once you have that, simply ask whether the node in question is amongst the subnodes of the reference node, or

If bottom-up, have a function that assembles the list of ancestors. Once you have that, simply ask wether the node in question is amongst the ancestors of the node in question.

Very likely the bottom-up approach is faster, regardless whether you have deep or wide trees.

Comment: I have added more information, that would be the basic solution but if in example I put these users in a database and when a user1 wants to edit user7 then I will have to make multiple queries to the database recursively until I get to user1 or top-down from user1 until I get to user7 to check if he has authorization. I think that so many queries will make it not scalable.

Comment: So you found out that hierarchical, recursive data is inefficient to store in a relational database. In your third edit you are caching the information for the bottom-up approach.

Comment: Yeah and I didn't know that recursive cte exists as trincot mentioned which is basically the same as walking up the tree bottom-up

Comment: That is my learning for today as well. :-)